# Sql Server - Field that hold value from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select p.ID,
       Received = (select Rec 
                   from Exp 
                   where EstAmt = (select MAX(ex.EstAmt) 
                                          from Exp ex 
                                          where ex.Prot = p.ID
                                            and EstAmt > 0)
                   )
From Prot 
where Received = 1
```

In the above, Received is a field I created as an alias that will get the value of what Rec is. Rec is a field in the table.

But when I put Received in the where clause I get: Invalid Column Name 'Received'. As mentioned, Received is not a field in the table but a place hold er that gets the value from the subquery. Any idea on how i can have Received in the where clause as I need to show the result only if that value is 1.

Comment: U cant keep sub-queries in SELECT clause....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to filter the results of your original query, using it as a sub query:

```
select * from
(
    select p.ID,
           Received = (select Rec from Exp  
                       where EstAmt = (select MAX(ex.EstAmt) from Exp ex
                                       where ex.Prot = p.ID and EstAmt > 0)
                      )   

 From Prot 
 ) subsel
 where Received = 1
```

Comment: @NatePet I see you used my answer in your new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740065/sql-server-subquery-with-case. Please, don't forget to upvote/accept this answer if it helped you (and I believe it did, since you are using it in another questions)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to select where it is on1, move the whole subquery to the where clause and compare it with 1.  You don't need to select it if you know what it is...

(I know this doesn't answer the how do you where on a subquery but it solves your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    select 
        p.ID,
        Received = (select Rec from Exp where  EstAmt = (select MAX(ex.EstAmt) from Exp ex where ex.Prot = p.ID
                         and EstAmt > 0)
                         )   
     From Prot
) AS t
where 
     Received = 1
```